# How to delete column in 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like this

```
[
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]],
[[3,8,9], [2,9,4]],
[[7,1,3], [1,3,6]]
]
```

I want it like this after deleting first column

```
[
[[2,3], [5,6]],
[[8,9], [9,4]],
[[1,3], [3,6]]
]
```

so currently the dimension is 3*3*3, after removing the first column it should be 3*3*2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can slice it as so, where `1:` signifies that you only want the second and all remaining columns from the inner most array (i.e. you 'delete' its first column).

```
>>> a[:, :, 1:]
array([[[2, 3],
        [5, 6]],

       [[8, 9],
        [9, 4]],

       [[1, 3],
        [3, 6]]])
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you are using numpy I'll mention numpy way of doing this. First of all, the dimension you have specified for the question seems wrong. See below

```
x = np.array([
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]],
[[3,8,9], [2,9,4]],
[[7,1,3], [1,3,6]]
])
```

The shape of x is

```
x.shape
(3, 2, 3)
```

You can use [numpy.delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) to remove a column as shown below

```
a = np.delete(x, 0, 2)
a
array([[[2, 3],
    [5, 6]],

   [[8, 9],
    [9, 4]],

   [[1, 3],
    [3, 6]]])
```

To find the shape of a

```
a.shape
(3, 2, 2)
```